# Why button can't correctly send intent to make hard-reset

Tags: java, android

I need to do a Hard reset on phone, when button clicked.
I think that problem is somewheare in permissions in manifest or in fact that some permissions on new versions of android need to be called.
I don't know what to fix and what's the problem. I'll be very grateful if you'll write decision.

**Main Activity**

```
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
    ComponentName mDeviceAdmin;

    public static class WipeDataReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            //2.2+
            mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            mDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, WipeDataReceiver.class);
        }

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                OnReset(currentAPIVersion);
            }
        });
    }

    private void OnReset(int currentAPIVersion){
        if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            // 2.2+
            if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdmin)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdmin);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Process will remove user installed applications, settings, wallpaper and sound settings. Are you sure you want to wipe device?");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
            } else {
                // device administrator, can do security operations
                mDPM.wipeData(0);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="141dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="193dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="141dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="342dp"
        android:text="Do Hard Reset"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="69dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="129dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="69dp"
        android:text="Будьте осторожны с этим приложением"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and 
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.hard_reset_by_google">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
        tools:ignore="ManifestOrder,ProtectedPermissions" />

</manifest>
'''
```